# Xamarin ios app sent email is never received

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have created a simple Xamarin App and would like to send a email.

**My Setup**

- Ipad
- Default email account 'Gmail'
- Ipad connected to Mac
- Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin ios singleview app
- Visual studio 2017 connected successfully to Mac
- Apple development certificate, provisioning
  profile has been setup up correctly

**My Code**

I have this simple code to send an email

```
  private void SendEmail()
        {
            MFMailComposeViewController mailController;

            if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
            {

                mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();

                // do mail operations here
                mailController.SetToRecipients(new string[] { "abe.uwe@gmail.com" });
                mailController.SetSubject("mail test");
                mailController.SetMessageBody("this is a test", false);

                mailController.Finished += (object s, MFComposeResultEventArgs args) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(args.Result.ToString());
                    args.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
                };

            }

        }
```

I call SendEmail() in AppDelegate FinishedLaunching.

**Result**
CanSendEmail returns true however the email is not received, checked my spam folders as well.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating `MFMailComposeViewController` but never presenting it to the user.  The user has to be the one to actually send the message.

```
this.PresentViewController(mailController, true, null);
```

Comment: I do not have access to PresentViewController as I am in AppDelegate.

Comment: why are you doing this in AppDelegate?  MFMailComposeViewController has to be shown to the user so it should be done after you have some UI presented, not before.

Comment: if you are trying to send an automated e-mail without user action, then MFMailComposeViewController will NOT work for you

Comment: I am doing this in AppDelegate as it will a default email for debugging purposes and will be disabled in the live app. There is no user input required.

Comment: the iOS API will not let you do this, sorry.  You have to let the user actually complete the UI interaction to send the e-mail

Answer (score 0):

If `this.PresentViewController` is not possible in your situation, you could also use:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(mailController, true, null);
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to  Xamarin iOS, when i include your code in Send Mail method i get object reference error. KeyWindow is null.  What am i missing?

Comment: First you have to set the initial UIViewController before you can call SendEmail();